# NullPointerException on overlap in libgdx (Java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, libgdx

I'm making a simple Java game as part of me learing it and when I run it I get a:

> `Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.mattihase.floatingpoint.GameScreen.generalUpdate(GameScreen.java:65)
>       at com.mattihase.floatingpoint.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:42)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:207)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)`

this is the general update line it's talking about and the lines under it:

```
if(pc.bounds.overlaps(gary.Rbounds))
    //where i test a bunch of booleans to see what the dialog returned should be
    //yes, i know i'm probably doing the ifs it unoptimized but i couldn't get it to
    //work the other way.
    //the pc.bounds stuff is there to make it follow the player character around the
    //world as the camera already does this.
      {
        if(pc.onquest = false){
            if(pc.finishquest = false){
            Assets.font.draw(batch, gary.Gdio, pc.bounds.x - 250, pc.bounds.y - 190);
            pc.onquest = true;
            }
        }
        if(pc.onquest = true){
            if(pc.finishquest = false){
            Assets.font.draw(batch, gary.GDdio, pc.bounds.x - 250, pc.bounds.y - 190);
            }
            }
        if(pc.haspoints = true){
            pc.finishquest = true;
        }
        if(pc.finishquest = true);
        Assets.font.draw(batch, gary.GCdio, pc.bounds.x - 250, pc.bounds.y - 190);
        pc.onquest = false;
        pc.award = true;
    }`
```

and these are the classes for the playercharacter and npc (called pc (class PlayerCharacter) and gary (class Rectoid) respectively)
the player character

```
public Sprite image;
public Rectangle bounds;
public int score;
public String scoreprint;
public boolean onquest;
public boolean finishquest;
public boolean haspoints;
public boolean award;

public PlayerCharacter(){
    onquest = false;
    haspoints = false;
    finishquest = false;
    award = false;
    score = 0;
    image = Assets.s_pc;
    bounds = new Rectangle(256-16, 192-16, 16, 16);
    scoreprint = score + "";`
```

and the gary
   `public Sprite Rimage;
    public Rectangle Rbounds;
    public String Gdio;
    public String GDdio;
    public String GCdio;

```
public Rectoid()
{
    Rimage = Assets.s_rectoid;
    Rbounds = new Rectangle(1024, 64, 64, 32);
    Gdio = "the diolog";
    GDdio = "the diolog";
    GCdio = "the diolog";`
```

c

Comment: Are you aware that sentences like 'pc.onquest = false' are assingements thar return the assigned value?

Comment: i am a bit of a n00b, can you please elaborate as to why that might be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, to check equality in objects references or for primitive types you have to use `==` operator. In lines like `if(pc.onquest = false){` you are assigning `false` to `onquest`, instead of checking its value. 
The reason why the code compiles is because in Java an assignment returns the assigned value.
For example the sentence:

```
int zero = 0;
if (zero == 0){} //its true
if (zero = 0){} //compile error, becouse 'zero = 0' returns '0', the asigned value
```

What is happening in your code is that you are using boolean variables.

```
if(pc.bounds.overlaps(gary.Rbounds))
  {
    if(pc.onquest = false){ // HERE YOU ARE DOING TWO THINGS: assing false to 
                            // onquest and return false. The following code is never execute 
        if(pc.finishquest = false){ // SAME HERE
        Assets.font.draw(batch, gary.Gdio, pc.bounds.x - 250, pc.bounds.y - 190);
        pc.onquest = true;
        }
    }
    if(pc.onquest = true){// SAME HERE
        if(pc.finishquest = false){// SAME HERE
        Assets.font.draw(batch, gary.GDdio, pc.bounds.x - 250, pc.bounds.y - 190);
        }
        }
    if(pc.haspoints = true){// SAME HERE
        pc.finishquest = true;
    }
    if(pc.finishquest = true);// SAME HERE
    Assets.font.draw(batch, gary.GCdio, pc.bounds.x - 250, pc.bounds.y - 190);
    pc.onquest = false;
    pc.award = true;
}`
```

Also, to check the value of a boolean just use it, no compare it to true or false, And make use of `!` operator.

Just simple use `if(!pc.onquest){` If you want to check if onquest is disabled.

About the NullPointerEception, probably gary variable is null. Check if you has create it before. It should be something like:

```
Rectoid gary = new Rectoid();
```